# Does the following set form a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I have a set of all real-valued functions denoted by $A^j(\mathbb R)$ with a continuous $j$-th derivative where $j$ is a positive integer. I am asked if the set forms a subgroup of the group $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ under componentwise multiplication. Can anyone show me how to approach this problem? I have proved existence of identity, but I have no clue about closure.

What I am specifically confused about is: 
If I say $f$, $g$ $\in$ $A^j(\mathbb R)$, it means that $f$ and $g$ both have continuous $j$-th derivative. Is it true that $f$.$g$ also have continuous $j$-th derivative? Any counterexample if this is false?

Comment: Hint: use product rule and induction on $j$.

Comment: Under component-wise multiplication, what's the inverse of the zero function? or of any function that vanishes, even if only at a single point?

Comment: @GerryMyerson if I understand you correctly, the inverse of the zero function simply does not exist. So, building off of that, I can say that $f(x) = 0$ $\in$ $A^j(\mathbb R)$ since its derivative is 0 and hence always continuous, but it does not have any inverse, and hence the set under consideration cannot be a subgroup. Right?

Comment: The problem, Ufo, is that $X$ can't be a subgroup of $Y$ if $Y$ isn't a group to begin with.

Comment: Do you understand, Ufo?

Comment: Yes GerryMyerson. Thanks a lot. :)